# Sonata Admin Bundle List with FosUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata

I want to show in the list according to connected user.
Now, my list shows all data.

my code :

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        unset($this->listModes['mosaic']);

        $listMapper
            /*->addIdentifier('id', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 12.5%',    
            ])*/
            ->add('date', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14.2%',    
            ])
            ->add("nombreMatch", null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14.2%',    
            ])
            ->add('cote', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14.2%',    
            ])
            ->add('mise', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14.2%',    
            ])
            ->add('gain', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14.2%',    
            ])
           ->add('benefice', null, array('template' => '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/Special/benefice_field_list.html.twig'))
           ->add('bankroolCourante', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14.2%',    
            ])
        ;
    }
```

How do I do ? I hope someone has a good solution.
thank for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You will have to overwrite the listAction method in the CRUDcontroller. Therefor you have to [create your custom CRUD controller](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html#extending-the-admin-controller) that extends the default one. In your controller you should overwrite the listAction. You could start with the code from the original listAction in the original CRUD controller which can be found in the src/controller directory inside the bundle.